# Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предложение такое: "В июне этого года в Сочи проходило 45-е заседание Межгосударственного совета по стандартизации, метрологии и сертификации, в который входят страны, участники СНГ".
Меня тут смущает оборот "страны, участники СНГ". Правильно ли употреблен оборот или лучше было бы сказать "страны, члены СНГ"? Но "члены" звучит как-то... не очень красиво.
И второй вопрос: правильно ли написано "45-е" - нужно ли "е" после цифры или было бы достаточно "45 заседание"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: "В июне этого года в Сочи проходило 45-е заседание Межгосударственного совета по стандартизации, метрологии и сертификации, в который входят страны - члены СНГ".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Это стандартное оформление для подобных конструкций, например: (1)"В целом уровень тарифов в отношении товаров российского происхождения, импортируемых в новые страны ― члены ЕС, снизится в среднем с 9% до около 4%". (2)Во-вторых, возможно увеличение «дальнего» мясоимпорта по «теневым» схемам по бестаможенному коридору через Белоруссию, Казахстан, Киргизию и Таджикистан, то есть через страны ― члены Таможенного союза СНГ".

ПРАВИЛО

Одно тире ставится при тесной смысловой связи приложения и определяемого слова в простом предложении. Такое тире условно можно назвать тире-дефисом, так как приложение и определяемое слово произносятся слитно, например: "Специальное устройство –  акваланг (пауза) используется при работе подводников".

ЗАПИСЬ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОГО

Падежные окончания в порядковых числительных, обозначенных арабскими цифрами, должны быть:
однобуквенными, если последней букве числительного предшествует гласный звук: 5-й (пятый, пятой), 5-я (пятая), но не 5-ый, 5-ой;
двухбуквенными, если последней букве числительного предшествует согласный: 5-го, 5-му, 30-ми, но не 5-ого, 5-ому, 30-ыми.

http://www.altaicpp.ru/begining/howtrue/read/chisldocs.html